# Going crazy on why fonts aren't loading on mobile

Tags: css, import, font-face

I cannot figure out why my fonts aren't loading on mobile, but they are working fine on desktop. I was originally adding my fonts inline in the header(strictly for the environment I was working in). I am now importing my fonts as a separate scss file, but here is my imports:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Regular';
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("/../fontPath/../Regular-Regular.otf") format("opentype")
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-Regular.eot") format("eot");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Regular';
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url("/../fontPath/../Regular-Semibold.otf") format("opentype")
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-Semibold.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-Semibold.woff") format("woff"),
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-Semibold.eot") format("eot");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Regular';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("/../fontPath/../Regular-SemiboldItalic.otf") format("opentype")
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-SemiboldItalic.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-SemiboldItalic.woff") format("woff"),
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-SemiboldItalic.eot") format("eot");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Regular';
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url("/../fontPath/../Regular-BlackItalic.otf") format("opentype")
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-BlackItalic.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-BlackItalic.woff") format("woff"),
       url("/../fontPath/../Regular-BlackItalic.eot") format("eot");
}

html {
  font-family: 'Regular', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the fonts that will work on mobile devices.

You will need the truetype (ttf) to work well on Android and iOS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

You can check more details here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I feel kinda silly, but I figured out the problem was I was missing a comma after otf file